# Logic behind precedence of operators

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

What is the motive for a compiler to follow specific precedence among the operators. Why was it not designed just by the order in which the code is written. I mean, why `"a + b * c"` is treated as `"(b * c) + a"` ? why not just follow the same order of how it is written? Every time I try to learn a programming language I have hard time memorizing the precedence/priority. Is there an easy way to master it?

Comment: For arithmetic it's quite obvious. You'd want the math to be executed correctly without manually writing the expression in BEDMAS order yourself. The whole point of a "high level language" is to have "high level constructs", such as correct arithmetic.

Comment: `a + b * c` can also be treated as `a + (b * c)`, this is (intentionally) not specified in c.

Comment: About your specific example: do you know arithmetic?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming language, this is how basic arithmetic works.

Comment: Thanks for taking me back to school (BEDMAS) . This question was not specific to programming, but in general was trying to find the answer on why the mathematicians agreed on * getting a precedence over + or why + gets precedence over bit-wise operators. Most of the websites talk about the precedence but none I could find explaining the reason why it is the the way it is.

Comment: Well, ask on a maths site!

Comment: Not all programming languages handle this question the same way. SML lets you set operator precedences manually. Smalltalk has no precedence and does as you suggest above. TCL has no genuine expressions and its arithmetic engine can be replaced.

Comment: @Sandeep Because _3x + 2y_ (meaning `(3 * x) + (2 * y)` and not `(((3 * x) + 2 ) * y )`) occur so often that having to write _(3x) + (2y)_ would be really annoying.

Comment: The origin is most likely that mathematicians are obsessed with creating obscure names and conventions for everything. This serves two purposes: 1) posing and 2) making it as hard as possible for unwanted outsiders to learn the trade. Almost every trade in history has used such "guild-thinking". Programmers are the very same - most of the C language completely lacks rationales and they have intentionally made some things hard to understand. Operator precedence, associativity and order of evaluation are perfect examples of such irrational nonsense, designed for posing-purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It would actually be easier to write parsers / compilers without having to deal with operator precedence. In such a case, the arithmetic would simply be performed from left to right.

Example:
10+20*30 => (10+20)*30 => 30*30 => 900

So, why deal with operator precedence?
It comes from Mathematics (Arithmetic) and was just a practice that people chose to follow. It should not be a bother since all languages have approximately the same operator precedence, you wouldn't need to learn operator procedence for each language. Even better, brackets or paranthesis have the highest priority, so you can use them if you are not sure.

You might want to read why the [BODMAS](https://www.quora.com/Why-and-how-was-the-BODMAS-rule-formed) rule was created in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is like in ordinary math rules. You have priorities for functions and operations.
If you'd like to change priority, then you have to use brackets or different order for operands.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precidence in C closely matches basic arithmetic [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).  But you're right, there are other sets of rules.

One alternative that lots of people in programming classes learn is [reverse-polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Actually, engineering schools in the 70s used to teach reverse-polish notation in regular math classes because it's how HP calculators used to function.  It's a much simpler method for computers to handle and is very similar to how a processor processes data using the stack.